# Stop theme displaying comments

Tags: plugin-development, comments

So with all comments disabled on pages/posts theme's still display any existing comments.

Is there a way to programmatically stop this happening without adjust the theme's code?

My plugin uses comments as a journalling type system to log all changes to (custom) posts. On the front end, when my client is logged in there are a number of pages the plugin provides and I do not want the comments to be displayed, but even with comments turned off, existing comments (journal entries) are shown at the foot of the page, which I do not want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I figured this out...

```
    add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'no_comments' ) );

    function no_comments()  {
        add_filter( 'get_comments_number', '__return_false' );  
    }
```

Removes the comment count and the comments themselves